# How to disable all MariaDB storage engine except MyISAM?

Tags: innodb, myisam, mariadb

(in `my.cnf`) I've tried `default-storage-engine = myisam`, `skip-innodb`, and commented out every innodb features, but none of them works

Answer (score 2):

Maria can't disable the Aria/Maria storage engine as it's needed. You can disable most of the others via

skip-innodb
skip-pbxt
skip-federated

just type the following to show all storage engines available and it's current status

```
mysql> SHOW PLUGINS;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your mysql config file

`disabled_storage_engines="MyISAM,BLACKHOLE,FEDERATED,ARCHIVE"`

It's must be usefull for mysql5.7.

Answer (score -2):

I think InnoDB cannot be disabled since this is killer feature of MariaDB

Comment: This is not correct.